# How to find out, where is the reference, a <member type="way" points to in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

I have an xml which describes a bicycle route in OpenStreetMap.
http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2764576

It seems to contain the route, that I'm interested in, but the

```
<relation id="2764576" visible="true" version="301" changeset="24078653" timestamp="2014-07-11T09:41:38Z" user="FlorianPerucchetti" uid="2070989">
    <member type="way" ref="207910997" role=""/>
    <member type="way" ref="38423641" role=""/>
    <member type="way" ref="4605681" role=""/>
    .....
```

So my questions are: where are the referenced ways, how to find them? How to get the route's coordinates I am interested in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number in the `ref` attribute is the way ID. Hence you can retrieve it likewise via the API, e.g. [way 207910997](http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/207910997). The way will have refs again to each of its node. These nodes can be fetched the same way from the API.

Another nice feature: You can also append [/full](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Full:_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2F.5Bway.7Crelation.5D.2F.23id.2Ffull) to your URL (http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2764576/full) and it will retrieve all referenced elements (ways and nodes), too.

Comment: Oh, thank you! It's quite obvious, I don't know how I could miss it.